# How to another root categories product to default categories product in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

Here As you can see in screen shot I have to auction categories Which is in default category and product add in another root category auction.how to show product of another root category to my own default root categories store on click auction in default navigation menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a default Magento feature available you can add one product to multiple categories.

the open product on categories tabs you can set multiple categories with root category. see below image

[image]

Comment: Hi Chirag Thanks for your response. Here my customer wants to sap rate product from default category. if I put my product in multiple categories then this product is also show during catalogue search in magento default store.  customer wants to put product in another root category only because they does not want to show product during catalogue search.  and they also not want to make another store for this root categories. trying to show another root category product in default category by using another root category product.